# Clauses with costants and unification

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

We have two set of clauses:

$S1 = \left \{ P(x),a \right \}
$
 and 
$S2 = \left \{ P(y),b \right \}
$

I have two questions:

1)Why it's possible to represent a clause with only a constant ?( im speaking about the constants a and b) Since constants are not predicates, what is the meaning of a clause with only a constant inside ?

2)How it's possibile to unificate this 2 sets since $a\neq b$ ?

Comment: In first-order logic we have *terms*: variables and constants, and *formulas*. **If** $a$ is a *constant* (i.e. a term) it is **not** a formula. *Clauses* are formulas.

Comment: So in my example a and b are predicates with 0 arity ?

Comment: **If** $a$ and $b$ are $0$-ary predicates, they are propositions (like in prop calculus); thus, is better to write $S_1= \{ P(x), Q \}$ and $S_2= \{ P(y), R \}$. We can use a new *individual constant* $c$ to get: $ P(c), Q$ and  $P(c), R$ ... and we are stuck.

Comment: @Qwerto Where did you get this example from?